# TextBox Validating does not trigger Button Click? C# .net 6 WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

If validated true, perform a button click, This is a simple example of the behavior I'm looking for, I know I can get the same result in another way.

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
            {
                button1.PerformClick();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Are you leaving the TextBox (moving the focus to another Control), to activate the validation events?

Comment: Is there something special about the button (the button must be enabled, visible and focusable for this to work)  and the event needs to be wired up. Have you debugged that you actually reach the PerformClick call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes that the button1_Click and textBox1_Validating event handlers are properly wired up to their respective events, which is typically done in the Designer (via the Properties window or double-clicking the button), or programmatically in the Form's constructor or Load event, using syntax like this.button1.Click += this.button1_Click; and this.textBox1.Validating += this.textBox1_Validating;.

While this code should work, it's somewhat unconventional to perform a button click within a validation event. You may want to consider refactoring this logic into a separate method, which can be called by both the button1_Click and textBox1_Validating event handlers. This would make the code easier to read, understand, and maintain.